# Does Docker healthcheck always have to be conditional?

Tags: docker, health-check

I was recently reading up on the usage of healthchecks in Docker. I was trying to understand the limits of healthchecks in general and just had a question if Docker healthchecks always needed to be conditional.

I was thinking because healthchecks can be run at specific intervals of time, is it possible to use general commands like `apt-get update` or in general install new or update libraries being used inside the Docker image through healthcheck commands without actually triggering a condition where the healthchecks turns the container "unhealthy".

I know work like this can perhaps be automated with including cronjobs in Dockerfile, but I just got curious if it could be used in this manner as well as an alternative to perform repetitive tasks inside the containers like running a script at specific intervals without making the container unhealthy (the above example of installing of updating libraries is probably not a good example but still would love to know if that can be done as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Technically*, yes: you only need to make sure that the command you specified always returns *success*, i.e., a exit code of `0`.

You could do this by wrapping your task in a custom script that always exits with *success* or using logical operators in the shell command line like this:

```dockerfile
HEALTHCHECK CMD apt-get update || exit 0
```

But looking at your question, ***conceptually*: no, absolutely not!**

First of all this totally undermines the intended use of healthchecks, which is to only execute small commands to determine the current health of the container - and not to execute arbitrarily long running commands for maintenance tasks (see also the `timeout` option to `HEALTHCHECK`).

So this approach is an incredibly hacky misuse of the `HEALTHCHECK` directive. It could also cause you unexpected problems since your specified `HEALTHCHECK` may be overriden by child images or the configuration when starting your image.

The correct way to run commands periodically would be to run a cron daemon or [using a process manager](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/#use-a-process-manager) or something similar.

Second of all installing software updates inside a running container is very bad practice since (docker) [containers are meant to be ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#create-ephemeral-containers). The correct way to update your software is to (update and) rebuild the images and recreate the containers from the new images. (Even after installing updates within a running container you would have to restart the container in order to actually load the updated executables!)

If you find yourself in a situation leading you to "solutions" like this you probably need to rethink your overall architecture to better match *the docker way*^^

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation. Yes, I am aware I should not be using healthchecks for stuff like this. I was just trying to test out the extent to which healthchecks in general have control over a container.